# How to add up total of several rows that have a matching column

Tags: sql

I have a query that returns something like:

```
COMPANY | TOTAL
--------+------
   A    |  10
   B    |  15
   C    |  10
   A    |  5
   A    |  10
   B    |  5
   D    |  10
```

Using this, I want to return results like:

```
COMPANY | TOTAL
--------+------
   A    |  25
   B    |  20
   C    |  10
   D    |  10
```

This has to be pretty simple, I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
SELECT company, SUM(total)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY company
```

You can sort by sum appending

```
ORDER BY SUM(total) DESC
```

or by company

```
ORDER BY company
```

Comment: Are you really sure the sort order is the summed total rather than the company?

Comment: @APC: no, I'm not sure, that' the reason I told OP to use one sort or the other... but I think his problem was not sort :) Reading his example I cannot say which order is used...

Comment: Perfect. I was grouping-by both company and total. This actually helps me understand GROUP BY a lot better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  company, SUM(total)
FROM    mytable
GROUP BY
        company
```